# How to compile a .scss file that imports other .scss into one master css file using gulp

Tags: javascript, css, compilation, sass, gulp

### Task

I am attempting to compile a .scss file that is dependent on other .scss files into a single .css file using gulp.

### Where I am

What I am currently working with is a directory similar to the generalized directory below. In the directory below, the global.scss file imports file1.scss, file2.scss, and file3.scss.

```
sass
  |
  |-file1.scss
  |-file2.scss
  |-file3.scss
  |-global.scss
```

### What I Was Hoping For

I was hoping that the gulp-sass task I wrote would see the imports and recognize the dependencies that this global.scss file had and compile everything accordingly. Here is the gulp.task I wrote:

```
gulp.task('global-styling', function() {
      gulp.src('src/resources/sass/global.scss')
          .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError()))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/global.css'));
});
```

### The Error I Get

This error is thrown because the variables from the files that global.scss is dependent upon never got compiled or even noticed.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: src/resources/sass/global.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$light-font".
        on line 110 of src/resources/sass/global.scss
>>     color: $light-font;
   -----------^
```

### What I Need

If you haven't figured it out by now, I need to figure out how to write a gulp task that will create a single global.css file in my dist folder from the global.scss and its dependencies. Could someone please shed some light on how this is done using gulp.

Answer (score 1):

If you `import` everything in `global.scss` you shouldn't any have problems. I see an error in your `sass.logError()`, it's without `()`, also to `gulp.dest` you need to pass a folder path: `.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));` and it will create a file called `global.css` inside `dist/css`. Here is a working example:

**gulpfile.js**

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('global-styling', function() {
    gulp
        .src('./scss/base.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

**scss/global.scss**

```
@import 'var';

body {
    background-color: $light-font;
}
```

**scss/var.scss**

```
$light-font: blue;
```

Output in **dist/css/global.css**

```
body {
  background-color: blue; }
```

**gulpfile.js EDIT: with gulp-rename**

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('global-styling', function() {
    gulp
        .src('./scss/base.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename('name.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try this out. Now if I want to name the .css file that gets created in dist, how would I do that?

Comment: You can use an npm module called [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.